# JSDoc equivalent to Typescript's `as const`?

Tags: typescript, types, jsdoc

I'm in an old project that is too huge to easily convert to Typescript, so I've been using JSDoc instead. The Typescript feature that I can't figure out how to replicate in JSDoc is using `as const` to fully type the property names and values of a static object.

```
// In Typescript
const anObject = {hello: 'world'} as const;
// (type shows as {hello:'world'} instead of {hello:string}
```

Is there any equivalent for this in JSDoc? I've been completely unable to find anything that does this (`@readonly` and `@const` don't do it), so instead I have to basically copy-paste any static object as a type to be able to properly type these cases, which certainly isn't DRY.

Comment: I doubt it would exist. `as const` is a TS directive that allows you to use runtime code as compile time type. However, JSDoc is entirely separate from code and especially disassociated with runtime code. It allows you to annotate some things but it certainly doesn't have the entire flexibility of TS.

Comment: JSDoc type assertions are explained in the handbook https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#casts So my guess would have been `/** @type {const} */ (1)` but it does not work.

Comment: @VLAZ That's not true whatsoever. TypeScript has nothing to do with the runtime either. There are instances where you can use `as const` to use a value as a type, but that has nothing to do with the runtime, nor is it only for that. It tells TS that the entire value is immutable.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Since Typescript 4.5:

```js
const foo = /** @type {const} */ ({x: 1});
const bar = /** @type {const} */ ("baz");
```

Note that the parentheses are required; this is cast syntax, not normal type annotation.

Comment: the note on parentheses was very helpful!  your note says this was since v4.5, however I believe [you may be referring to v2.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-5.html#type-assertioncast-syntax-in-checkjsts-check-mode)? and [shown in the handbook here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#casts)

I also can confirm this works with tuples

```const test = /** @type {const} */ (["hello",42]); // [string,number]```

Comment: @bristweb I'm referring to const assertions, which were only added to Typescript in 3.4 and JSDoc in 4.5. JSDoc cast syntax goes back earlier, but `const` was not a supported type before 4.5.